# Angular directive repeats only the last element

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create an "instrument" directive. I have added three instruments to my index.html, but instead of showing them all, I see that the last one is repeated three times:
[image]

```js
/**
 * Created by Shalmu Y. on 26.05.2015.
 */
/* @flow */
"use strict";
(function () {
  const app = angular.module('Lesson3', []);
  app.directive('instrument', function () {
    return {
      restrict:'E',
      link: function (scope, el, attr) {
        function cap(s){  return s.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+ s.substr(1);    }
        scope.strain = cap(attr.kind);
        scope.caption = cap(attr.name);
      },
      template:'<span style="padding:4px; border:2px dotted #080;">{{strain}} - {{caption}}</span>'
    };
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Created by Shalmu Y. on 26.05.2015 -->
<html ng-app="Lesson3">
<head lang="en">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Lesson 3</title>
</head>
<body>
    <instrument kind="brass" name="trumpet"></instrument>
    <instrument kind="string" name="guitar"></instrument>
    <instrument kind="woodwind" name="clarinet"></instrument>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had a similar problem, I solved adding: scope:true into return{}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have scope in directive, so parent scope is used.
So in fact you have only one scope.strain and scope.caption.

What u can do is to add to directive:

```
scope : {
  strain: '=kind',
  caption: '=name'
}
```

Remove your link function and use uppercase filter in directive template.

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/88E6vMWPguLlZ4MhWtoA?p=preview)